# C# Monitor.Wait/Pulse not visible?

Tags: c#, xna, monitor

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx), the Wait/Pulse/PulseAll methods are static members of the System.Threading.Monitor class. However, when I attempt to access these operations, Visual Studio's intellisense dose not show these operations (only the Enter, TryEnter, and Exit operations). When I attempt to compile my application using these operations, I get the "System.Threading.Monitor does not contain a definition for ..." error.

Can anyone tell me why these operations not available? Are there any dependencies (other than the mscorlib reference) to use these operations? note: I'm using .Net 4

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to mention this. I'm using XNA.

Comment: Tags are our friends.